# SQL Query, Rails view, remove decimal place

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, format

I currently have this in my controller:

```
@softwares = Software.find_by_sql
(
"SELECT s.id, s.vendor, s.title, s.edition, SUM(l.amount) AS amount FROM softwares s
 LEFT JOIN licenses l ON s.id=l.software_id GROUP BY s.vendor, s.title, s.edition"
)
```

Which does what it's supposed to, but the number comes up as 7.0 or 6.0 instead of just 7 or 6.. how do i remove the decimal? In my view i literally just have `<%= l.amount %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes up as a decimal because l.amount is a decimal

try

```
 "SELECT s.id, s.vendor, s.title, s.edition, CAST(SUM(l.amount) as UNSIGNED) AS amount 
  FROM softwares s 
  LEFT JOIN licenses l ON s.id=l.software_id GROUP BY s.vendor, s.title, s.edition"
```

Comment: it didn't come up as a decimal before i put the sum in, and i'm doing the same thing with a different controller, which works fine! Sorry where do i need to put that?

Comment: `Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int, SUM(l.amount)) AS amount FROM softwares s`

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather put control over presentation to view. Instead of

```
<%= l.amount %>
```

put:

```
<%= number_to_currency l.amount, :precision => 0 %>
```

This helper method is described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html)

On a side note, it may be a better design to put that SQL into model. Controller then does something like `@softwares = Software.all_with_licenses_amounts`